# Dynamic task execution in Airflow

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

Consider I have a airflow DAG contains three tasks t1,t2,t3. The flow of the DAG would be
`t1>>t2>>t3`.
I want to find a way to change the starting task dynamically. If I give t1 in runtime the DAG should be triggered from t1. If I give t2, then t1 should be skipped and DAG execution should start from t2. Is there a way to do this in airflow?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way but not as you describe it.
add `t0` as `BranchPythonOperator` which will decide if continue to `t1` or skip it and continue to `t2`.

```
def choose(ti):
    if something:
        return 't1'
    return 't2'

t0 = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='t0',
    python_callable=choose)

t1 = DummyOpeartor(task_id='t1')
t2 = DummyOpeartor(task_id='t2', trigger_rule='one_success')
t3 = DummyOpeartor(task_id='t3')

t0 >> [t1, t2] >> t3
t1 >> t2
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Will it work for any number of tasks? What is the usage of one_success here

Comment: t2 will have only 1 parent in Success the other one will be in Skipped since the default trigger rule is all_success you must modify it to one_success. I'm not sure what it means any number of task. can you be more specific?

Comment: If we have tasks namely t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7. Will this method will provision to start the pipeline from any task? Sorry for the delayed comment

Comment: the return of `choose` can be a list of `task_ids`